# Can we merge the [type-conversion] and [data-type-conversion] tags?

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

Just identified a possible tag overlap; is there any reason to think these tags are distinct:

[type-conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/type-conversion)

> Type conversion is the way of implicitly or explicitly changing an entity of **one data type into another**. This is done to take advantage of certain features of type hierarchies or type representations.

[data-type-conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/data-type-conversion)

> In computer science, type conversion, type casting, and coercion are different ways of, implicitly or explicitly, changing an entity of **one data type into another**.

Seems pretty clear-cut that they're the same, even using the same phrasing in their descriptions.

Any reason not to merge?

(given [type-conversion] is a) more concise and b) more mature (in terms of # of tagged posts), it seems natural for [type-conversion] to inherit [data-type-conversion] posts)

Comment: Should this be [tag:support] not [tag:feature-request]?

Comment: I agree; they appear to mean exactly the same thing.

Comment: Almost a year and no one saw this?

Comment: Both tag wikis were copy-pasted from Wikipedia. One with attribution, the other without. Heh. Clearly a good candidate for a merge. So...now done.

Comment: @CodyGray there is also [tag:typeconverting] that means the same and has no wiki. We should merge that too

Comment: Seems clear-cut. Done, @Vadim.

Answer (score 5):

I think that this should happen - these mean the exact same thing. I'm not sure why the extra tag was created to begin with.

Since the [burnination request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355395/should-we-burninate-the-convert-tag) for the [convert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/convert) tag is going forward, that adds one more reason to do this (given that a fair number of those questions will likely end up with one of these tags).