# The [convert] tag has been burninated

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request, blocklist-request

*This tag has been burninated. Please do not recreate it. If you need advice on which tag to use, see the answer below. If you see this tag reappearing, it may need to be blacklisted.*

---

The [convert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/convert) tag currently has no tag wiki and 868 questions (growing all the time). I propose that it be burninated.

To address the standard tests for burnination requests:

> Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

No, "convert" is ambiguous and isn't even a real topic. Someone can't really be an expert in "convert."

> Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

Possibly, given that it could refer to programming topics.

> Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

No, none whatsoever.

> Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

No, not even close. Looking at the tagged questions, it's used to refer to numerous different concepts (typecasting, converting between file types, converting between languages, etc.) and it's unclear which one is "correct."

One of the ImageMagick command line tools is "convert", but a previous burnination effort created a [imagemagick-convert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/imagemagick-convert) tag specifically for programming questions about that tool.

---

Also, since this was previously burninated ([once back in 2011](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78937/shouldnt-the-convert-tag-be-burninated), and then [again in 2012](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348540/can-we-remove-the-convert-tag)), yet keeps coming back, I suggest that it be blacklisted as well.

Comment: You haven't really answered the standard questions, just asserted "No" to all of them. Why is "convert" a bad tag, exactly?

Comment: Looks like most of the questions are either about **transcoding** (one file format to another) or **casting** (one datatype to another).

Comment: @DidierL: the core argument isn't that we don't have the experts, the argument is that we can show `convert` to be a meaningless tag because you can't meaningfully expect "experts in general conversion" -- anywhere, ever. Given that "lack of experts" is indeed not a valid reason for burnination on its own, though, it's best to avoid it even as an example. It's enough to say `convert` is clearly ambiguous and leave it at that. Obviously, we could (and probably do) have experts on every specific thing `convert` could refer to. (Like T-SQL's `CONVERT`, I'd call myself an expert on that, why not.)

Comment: @JeroenMostert Yes, that's a good summary - I'm not even sure what it would *mean* to be an expert in that. By definition, a tag should be something that someone could conceivably be an expert in. For example, we have a [c#] tag because you could be an expert in C#. We have a [data-structures] tag because you could be an expert in [data-structures]. After all, the primary point of having tags in the first place is to help connect people who want to answer questions with questions that they're likely to know the answer to.

Comment: @EJoshuaS the point is not about whether there could be experts or not. It does not matter for a burninate request. The matter is whether the tag hurts the site and is it worth the effort to burninate it. I don't say it isn't btw. We might be missing statistics though: maybe for example `convert` actually means `type-conversion` (or is it `data-type-conversion`?) 99% of the time, and should just be made a synonym of it after fixing the remaining 1%.

Comment: And to throw more gas on the fire, [`convert`](http://imagemagick.org/script/convert.php) is one of ImageMagick's command line tools, used to something something image files from one format to another with optional graphical operations performed.

Comment: Question score is 80 (+84/-4) at the time of featuring.

Comment: If the litmus test is, "Would anyone subscribe to [convert]?" then I would guess it fails that test and should be burninated; is there any way to see subscriber (favourite) counts for a tag?

Comment: Yes, @Eterm, right there in the tag popup (when you look at the tag on the main site, not here on Meta). [convert] currently has 35 followers.

Comment: Maybe we should convert it. SCNR.

Comment: @CodyGray I'm personally slightly baffled as to why it has *any* followers, truthfully - how can someone be knowledgeable about "convert"? I'd be curious to see any them comment or answer here as to why.

Comment: I saw the convert tag before I saw this thread, and my instant thought was basically what you wrote.

Comment: Trogdor summoned, with a score of 156 (+162/-6). Didn't pick up much resistance. No surprise, given this tag has been removed twice before. We did get some great retagging advice, though.

Comment: @CodyGray What happens if someone tags a question with [convert] during burnination? Should you treat it the same as you treat the existing questions (i.e. DV and/or VTC if it's a bad question, otherwise edit the tags), or is it considered abuse or otherwise flag-worthy?

Comment: @EJoshuaS No, treat it the same as you would any other question tagged [convert]. They are both new users. No reason to assume any harm by it, they just didn't know any better. All this does is confirm that nobody reads the tag wiki excerpts when posting questions. Ideally, we might blacklist a tag while it's being burninated. I think that was the original plan, but blacklisting requires a CM to get involved, and needing a CM both at the beginning and the end of this process makes it even more cumbersome than it already is. A couple more questions over a week's time isn't a big deal.

Comment: Ah, and I see the update about the questions all being closed. Was heading out just now, but I will look again later, maybe tomorrow, and see about finishing this up, deleting the questions, and getting a CM to officially blacklist.

Comment: @CodyGray Is this blacklisted now as well?

Comment: @EJoshuaS No, not officially. I haven't gotten a CM to do that yet. It is on The List.

Comment: @CodyGray the tag [reappeared](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/convert) again.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

## [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) This tag has been *burninated*.

[image]

---

## Observations/Retag Guidance

- [imagemagick-convert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/imagemagick-convert) is used for questions about one of ImageMagick's command line tools, used to convert image files from one format to another with optional graphical operations performed (resizing, cropping, etc).
- [sql-convert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-convert) is used for a SQL function that converts an expression of one data type to another.
- [casting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/casting) is used for questions about converting a object type into another type if the conversion is allowed.
- [type-conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/type-conversion) is used for questions regarding conversion of various data types from one type into another (but not through casting).
- [number-formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/number-formatting) is used for questions about converting integer and float numbers to string.
- [data-conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/data-conversion), [format-conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/format-conversion), [file-conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/file-conversion) are used for questions regarding conversion of some amount of data into another type.
- [date-conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/date-conversion), [date-formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/date-formatting) are for questions about converting dates from one calendar or notation to another.
- [transcoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/transcoding) is used for questions about converting one file format to another (e.g. video and audio formats).
- [image-conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/image-conversion) is used for questions about converting between different image formats.
- [video-conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/video-conversion) is used for questions about converting between video formats. (Should probably be combined with [transcoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/transcoding) when re-tagging).
- [code-conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-conversion) is used for converting code written in one language to another language

There is also the [string-conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/string-conversion) tag that may overlap with some of the above.

Comment: We should probably figure out what to do with code-conversion questions ("I'm trying to convert this from Java to C#" kind of questions).

Comment: @EJoshuaS perhaps the [tag:code-conversion] tag? ;) (just added it to the wiki)

Comment: I'd like to get some extra attention to [this merge request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314147/can-we-merge-the-type-conversion-and-data-type-conversion-tags) to merge [tag:type-conversion] and [tag:data-type-conversion]. If we have these merged, when we go to phase 4, we don't have to arbitrarily retag to one of these if we retag questions about converting data types.

Comment: Should code-conversion be code-porting?

Comment: @DewiMorgan probably not. We have a [tag:porting] tag, but in the excerpt of the [tag:code-conversion] tag it states: _Not to be confused with porting, which deals with architectures/platforms._ Porting is more broad in that sense (but also handles converting code from one language to another language)

Comment: @Joshua People also use [tag:translate] for that.

Comment: @VladimirF That's not ambiguous at all, and not like that tag is full of Google Translate/internationalisation questions ;). I can feel a new burninate request coming.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth There is also [tag:code-translation]! We can make it a synonym for [tag:code-conversion]. Those [tag:translate] questions can be cleaned up then..

Comment: Does `string-conversion` refer to character encoding or something else?

Comment: Tried to think about how to retag the [tag:convert] in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43423584/decimal-to-binary-convert-in-c , and not sure about using [tag:data-conversion] or [tag:format-conversion], or another ?

Comment: @andy Reading the descirption of the tag, it seems more fitted for serialization or de-serialization of other types.

Comment: @pac0 `[casting]` is a good tag for the question you are looking at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43423584/decimal-to-binary-convert-in-c