# Re-burninate and blacklist the [convert] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, blocklist-request

Related: [The [convert] tag has been burninated](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355395/the-convert-tag-has-been-burninated)

For reasons that were discussed in the linked post, the [convert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/convert) tag was burninated just under 3 years ago.

In the meantime, it has reappeared and now has 88 questions. It's no better than it was last time. Can we re-burninate this and then blacklist the tag?

Comment: SE should give mods the ability to blacklist tags

Comment: @SamuelLiew I agree.

Comment: @BhargavRao if blacklisting requires SE staff involvement, should this be tagged [meta-tag:status-review]?

Comment: Using [status-review] is a good way to get SE staff attention, @gnat, that's true. However for this particular post, I'm not sure whether it needs to be escalated or not.

Comment: @BhargavRao I also pondered whether it is worth it. However after noticing that this is 4th burnination effort for this tag (prior attempts are listed in the opening reference) and that total amount of upvotes on these is now well over 200 I decided to propose that. Looks like in this particular case small dev effort would save us quite a bit of meta hassle and trouble

Comment: @gnat The issue is that blacklists are implemented on SE using regexes, so there's a performance hit when they add blacklists. That's the reason why staff are reluctant to add more to the blacklists. SE needs to re-architect the way tag blacklists are handled. Anyway, there's a [tool by SOBotics](https://rodgort.sobotics.org/zombies?onlyAlive=false) to check tags that have resurfaced, I used to keep an eye on that daily until Sep last year. Martijn and other mods were checking that recently, and have handled a lot of the tags. (I'm still not completely back into tag moderation for now)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[convert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/convert) was added to the block list this morning!

I discussed the warning message with Zoe and we came up with the following based on the commentary in the prior burnination request:

> The 'convert' tag is not allowed.
>
> Please use a more specific tag to describe the subject of your question. For example, "imagemagick-convert", "sql-convert", or "code-conversion".

Now people are guided to convert their [convert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/convert) tag to something else.

[image: Screenshot of an attempted tag edit that shows the error message quoted above.]