# Text incorrectly says "tab" instead of "tag" when a user looks at a tag with no questions

Tags: bug, tags, questions, user-interface

The [convert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/convert) tag recently [had all of its questions removed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/396922/re-burninate-and-blacklist-the-convert-tag), but the tag hasn't been purged from the system yet.

When you try to view it, you get the following text:
[image]

Shouldn't this read:

> Perhaps you'd like to select a different **tag**?

rather than

> Perhaps you'd like to select a different **tab**?

?

Comment: It's the same text as when you select a tag but there are no questions in the selected *tab*. Your problem will automatically resolve itself, though, in 6-8 time units.

Comment: I think it's referring to the buttons just on top - Newest, Active, Bountied, etc. Although, the message doesn't make sense for Newest - if there is nothing there, I doubt you'll find results elsewhere.

Comment: Cross-site post on MSE: ["Perhaps you'd like to select a different tab?" - shouldn't that be 'tag' instead of 'tab'?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/357321/289905).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't think it is a bug in the sense *they meant "tag", but wrote "tab" instead*.

The tabs the text is referring to are these:

[image]

The message makes sense when looking at "bountied" or "unanswered", but for the other tabs (that apply sorting, but not *filters*) is not very relevant.

In any case, I would say that it happens more often that someone looks at the "bountied" **tab** of a tag or tag combination without bountied questions, than a user looks at the listing for a **tag** (or tag combination) without any questions at all.

Comment: IIRC one of the older versions of the "new navigation", they were literally tabs in the traditional sense so this phrase was less unclear